# problem with nextgen plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, gallery

I have a problem with Nextgen gallery,after activating some plugins it doesn't show the submit buttons(`insert`, `cancel`).

Then i have deactivated all plugins, but that doesn't help.

I haven't any experience with wordpress, so any suggestions would be very useful.

Thanks much

Comment: Belongs maybe on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com - if it's answerable even there

Answer (score 1):

Two things I always try:

1) Make sure you're running PHP5 - follow these directions to upload a htaccess file enabling php5. http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=100045

2) Create a test site with a fresh install of wordpress on same server and see if the plugin works.

Hope this helps,
Shannon